# What is the standard deviation and mean return of oil?

Tags: stocks, risk, asset-allocation, portfolio, commodities

Let's use WTI.

I'd like to add oil to my portfolio, and I was wondering how much I should have. I'm in 60-70% index and 40-30% individual value stocks. I want to cut back on my value plays and add oil stock.

I know this question depends on risk tolerance; I'd like to maximize the risk adjusted return of my portfolio.

Comment: You probably don't really want to maximize the risk/reward. If you really did, you'd put all your investments in lotto tickets or something similar.

Comment: What do you mean by "maximize risk/reward"?  Taking all your money and put it on a single number at roulette will have a ton of reward and a ton of risk, but I suspect you want to maximize your risk-adjusted returns.

Comment: Yes David, I want to maximize my risk-adjusted returns. Like using the Sharpe Ratio. Please excuse my noobness.

Comment: @MattyMool there isn't a rule of thumb, and this question - worded as is - only invites opinion. Which we don't allow. It might be possible to reword it but I doubt it

Comment: Ok, I'll try to change it

Comment: Are you taking into consideration the value of the USD, which WTI is quoted in.   Over the past year, the USD has gained near 33% against the euro, making it seem like the price of oil is dropping more than it actually did.  (correct me if I'm wrong, but it now takes more euro's to buy the same amount of oil, so in reality it hasn't fallen as far for Europeans as it did in the USA)  If they're predicting the dollar could gain another 10-20 % against foreign currencies, would that change your reasoning of jumping all in right away.

Answer (score 2):

Oil as a commodity or investing in oil companies as a stock?  As a commodity, I'd recommend none.

The article Commodities – [They Have (Almost) No Place in Your Portfolio](http://www.pragcap.com/commodities-they-have-almost-no-place-in-your-portfolio) and [The Case Against Commodities](https://www.betterment.com/resources/investment-strategy/the-case-against-investing-in-commodities/) explain why commodities are not good investments.

Comment: I'd like to add stock, I have my eye on a specific company, lets call that company "CVX". I have the correlation for CVX to WTI.

Comment: Nice articles, David, edited to cleanly show titles and links.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a moving target. And my answer will be subject to revision.
I disagree with the votes to close, as you are asking (imho) what role commodities and specifically oil, play in one's asset allocation. Right? *How much* may be opinion, but there's a place to ask *if*.

[image]

I'm looking at this chart, and thinking, long term, the real return is zero. The discussion regarding gold has been pretty exhausted. For oil, it's not tough to make the case that it will fluctuate, but long term, there's no compelling reason to believe its price will rise any faster than inflation over the really long term.